# Python for windows api hooking

Tags: api, winapi, hook, detours, easyhook

Is it possible to write the Windows API hook / DLL injection in Python (in conjunction with MS Detours or Easyhook as a framework)? I can't find really information about it, it seems that most of the people has written this code in C++ or C#?

Comment: Unclear what the question is asking for. It's plausible to be able to do the setup and DLL injection from Python code. On the other hand, it's inhibitively difficult to inject Python code, as that requires a complex execution environment to be set up. Python isn't a systems programming language. If you're trying to do systems programming tasks, pick a systems programming language.